# DASHBOARD ERROR

Tags: dashboard

I got an issue related to dashboards. One of the user has a problem. 
She says that the Chart is not reflecting new date once deal has been extended. This is a high priority issue that i need to solve, but the user is unavailable to get any more information. From the given information can you guyz let me know if there could be any rectification for this.

Thanks       .

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be dashboard refresh problem. Dashboard shows old data until your are not going to refresh the dashboard.

Click **Refresh** to load the latest data into the dashboard. The data is as current as the date and time displayed after As of... at the top right corner of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard might require a refresh, I hope the same field is updated for extending the deal or if it is captured in another field that has to be included in the report and in dashboard.